# Display text if statement matches

Tags: php

I am a beginner when it comes to php, and I have encountered a problem that I cannot find the solution for. I have tried searching for a relevant answer but I haven't found one.

I have the following code in my index.php:

```
<?php if ($set_status = 2) {
echo 'There is one or more errors';
} else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

and this a bit further down:

```
<?php include 'scan/a.php'; ?>
```

And inside my a.php I have the following code:

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents
('http://www.a-random-website/text.html', NULL, NULL, 2, 1);


if ($a == "0") {

include 'fail.php';

} elseif ($a == "1") {

include 'success.php';

} else {
    echo 'Offline';
}

?>
```

And inside my fail.php I have the following code:

```
<?php

$set_status = 2;

echo 'Failed';
?>
```

So the idea here is that "a.php" will fetch a number from the website (The correct website has either ["1"] or ["0"] displayed that the code will fetch).

Depending on the result it returns, a.php will include either "fail.php" or "success.php", each containing either a success or a fail-message. If file_get_contents return a 0 I also want fail.php to $set_status = 2; which will cause "There is one or more errors" to be displayed on the front-page (index.php).

The reason that I am using include is that there's going to be a "b.php" and "c.php" and "d.php" and so on, all doing the same thing but fetching data from different pages. I want the success or fail-message to remain easy to edit, without having to edit each and every new x.php file.

So here's where it gets problematic. Everything works beautifully, except for the "There is one or more errors"-message that's supposed to trigger if ($set_status = 2).

I can get as far as the message showing, but when I switch the 1 and 0 in "a.php" (To simulate a specific result) the message will still show. I can't seem to figure it out.

So my question is: What have I done wrong, and what is the correct way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Marc

Comment: go with ($setstatus==2) condition in comparison then you will get ..

Comment: You're using `=` instead of `==` in your `if` statement.

Comment: I think there is not value given to $set_status in index.php and echo statement is also empty so finally blank page....need to pass some vlaue to $set_status in index.php

Comment: More over in a.php  you don't need $a=='1' you need $a==1 same for other condition

Answer (score 1):

use `==` operator in index.php to compare

```
<?php if ($set_status == 2) {
echo 'There is one or more errors';
} else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($set_status ==2) {
echo 'There\'s one or more errors';
} else {
echo '';
}
?>
```

Just change this code ... see slash`\` and `==` in the echo line .. else of your code id fine